# mysql How to select fields that have the same value in another column AND the same value in another table's column?

Tags: mysql, database, select

This is part of a homework to be perfectly honest, not of such importance, but still.
So, lets suppose we have the following tables:

```
        Song                                      Singer_prod

composer     title                            singer      sing_title
   A          a1                                S1            b1
   A          a2                                S3            c3
   B          b1                                S3            c1
   C          c1                                S1            a1
   C          c2                                S1            a2
   C          c3                                S3            c2 
                                                S2            a1
```

Now, the question is to select those composers, whose every title has been sang by only one singer.
For instance, composer **B** has only one title, **b1**, sang only by **S1**.

Also, composer **C** has written **c1, c2,c3**, all sang only by **S3**.
Those two composers should show up in the results.

In contrast, from composer's **A** songs, **a2** was sang only by**S1** but **a1** was sang both by **S1** and by **S2**, so **A** shouldn't show up in the results.

I've tried countless combinations of nested SELECTS, GROUP BYs and WHEREs, with no luck so far. The only thing i'm pretty sure is that a count(singer)=1 should be needed somewhere, so far fruitlessly used though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: show us what you've tried so far

Comment: My best try so far has been approximately what Deluca answered below, 
something like:
SELECT composer, singer, title

FROM song
INNER JOIN singer_prod 
ON song.title = singer_prod.sing_title
GROUP BY composer
HAVING count( tragoudistis)=1;
Unfortunately, it still doesn't return what i was hoping. 
In any case, thanks for your interest, hope i'm getting close on!

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why it doesn't return what you are hoping for and what it is returning vs what you expect.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I found out that what is needed is a "DISTINCT" inside the count, count(distinct singer)=1; For some reason not completely clear to me!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Composer, Singer FROM Song x
INNER JOIN Singer_prod y on x.title = y.sing_title
GROUP BY Composer, Singer
HAVING COUNT(Distinct Singer) = 1
```

Comment: A good answer should include an explanation to make clear how it works. That way the poster, and any future visitors, will learn something rather than just copying and pasting code.

Comment: The above-mentioned SELECT  includes composers whose songs have been played by only one singer each. What is asked is that all one composer's songs have been sang by only one singer .